# Yii CompareBehavior / "scoring" models

Tags: oop, design-patterns, yii

I am building a Yii app in which a requirement is that a given model should be able to be compared to any existing model of the same type, and based on the comparison, the imported data either updates the existing model, makes a new model, or does nothing.[The Yii Framework Forum has a nice post](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/10285-how-to-compare-two-active-record-models/) about implementing a `Compare` behavior, which provides half of the equation.

I am confused about the appropriate place to place the "scoring" method specific to each model. For example, I might iterate over all the existing models and `compare($each)` to a given model, but that only spits out differences between attributes. It may be that for one model, I care about just `name` while for another model, I care about `birthday` and `color`.

Should I override the behavior to make it specific to each type of model, or does this defeat the purpose of having a behavior to begin with (then, all these behavior subclasses would be tied to the model class)?

Other ideas I've had include:

- Make an `IScorable` interface with a `getScore()` that models that are "scorable" may conform to
- Implement the strategy pattern, with many concrete strategies tied to model-specific scenarios

Comment: I dint exactly understand the question. Is this `name` ,`birthday` and `color` are attributes of same type of model or different?

Comment: Important is that you should not confuse the word _model_. A _model_ is typically the whole set of classes, a _class_ is a type in the model, where attributes and methods for that type are defined. An _object_ is a concrete example (or instance) of a class and has a value for each attribute of the class. At runtime there can be many objects of one class. So if you compare two things, that're always objects.

Regarding your question: I don't know Yii (so this is no answer), but the standard OOP rule is to implement class-specific behavior in the class.